# xml schema, multiple elements with same name but with different types error

Tags: xml, xsd, dtd, xml-validation

There are a ton of examples of this dilemma online but I still can't quite understand the best way to go about this.  I'm trying to create a schema that will:

- Check for specific element order/sequencing

  - Each element is mandatory, appears only 1x, and is always listed in the same order.
- Make sure element restrictions apply only to said element (including attribute names and values)

  - There's only one element with `type="System.Drawing.Size"` but multiple elements with `type="System.Boolean"` as well as `type="System.String"`.  The XML below is simplified for the sake of illustration.
  - There are a few elements with `type="System.String"` that have their own respective `<val>` restriction enumeration values.

NOTE: The XML structure I'm working with uses 'True' rather than 'true' (even though a `System.Boolean` will accept mixed-case variations of "TruE") so I have to restrict using `base="xs:string"` and an enumeration rather than relying on `xs:restriction base="xs:boolean"`.

I'm getting this error message when validating the xml below against the schema I have so far:

```
cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_Application.UserOptionsconfig'. Multiple elements with name 'option', with different types, appear in the model group.
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config>
    <Application.UserOptions>
        <option name="StartMaximized" type="System.Boolean">
            <val>False</val>
        </option>
        <option name="WindowSize" type="System.Drawing.Size">
            <val>1366, 768</val>
        </option>
    </Application.UserOptions>
</config>
```

XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="config">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Application.UserOptions">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="option">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="val">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:enumeration value="True"/>
                          <xs:enumeration value="False"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="StartMaximized"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="System.Boolean"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="option">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="val">
                      <xs:simpleType>
                        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                          <xs:pattern value="\d+,\s\d+"/>
                        </xs:restriction>
                      </xs:simpleType>
                    </xs:element>
                  </xs:sequence>
                  <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="WindowSize"/>
                  <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="System.Drawing.Size"/>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

- How can I fix this schema so that it still checks for element ordering and enforces the restrictions I've defined?
- Would validating against a DTD achieve what I'm trying to do, or is using XSD a better way to go?

I'm prepared for receiving a stiff tone from the community as the topic has been seemingly covered, but after looking at responses to questions similar to mine, I still cannot determine how to incorporate the restrictions I've laid out.

Comment: How are you performing the validation? It works validating like `xmllint --schema tmp.xsd --noout tmp.xml` with the samples provided as is.

Comment: I've used https://www.freeformatter.com/xml-validator-xsd.html and https://www.liquid-technologies.com/online-xsd-validator so far

Comment: Weird. It's valid [here](https://www.utilities-online.info/xsdvalidation) and invalid [here](https://easycodeforall.com/xsd_validation): `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 7; columnNumber: 27; cos-element-consistent: Error for type '#AnonType_Application.UserOptionsconfig'. Multiple elements with name 'option', with different types, appear in the model group.[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@38755291`

Comment: Validates using python `lxml` too.

Comment: First decision to make is: what are your technology constraints. Are you able to use XSD 1.1? Are you able to use XSD 1.0 + Schematron? Are you able to use Relax NG? (I don't mention DTDs because they will get you nowhere). A pure XSD 1.0 solution is not possible.

Comment: I don't think the way you want it is possible, you can not have two `option`s in there with a different type, unless perhaps with XSD 1.1 and conditional types.

Comment: I would add that the schema is definitely invalid (violates the `Element Declarations Consistent` constraint). Any XSD processor that accepts it is non-conformant with the spec. Of course, being non-conformant doesn't make it unusable, but it means you're taking a big risk.

Comment: Michael - Unfortunately I'm restricted to XSD 1.0 since I'm using .NET (unless .NET supports XSD 1.1 now, which I don't believe it does as of 9/2023).

Answer (score 0):

Sample XSD 1.1 using `xs:alternative` based on `type` attribute of `option`:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="config">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Application.UserOptions">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="option" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:alternative test="@type = 'System.Boolean'">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="val">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:enumeration value="True"/>
                            <xs:enumeration value="False"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="StartMaximized"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="System.Boolean"/>
                  </xs:complexType>                  
                </xs:alternative>
                <xs:alternative test="@type = 'System.Drawing.Size'">
                  <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                      <xs:element name="val">
                        <xs:simpleType>
                          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                            <xs:pattern value="\d+,\s\d+"/>
                          </xs:restriction>
                        </xs:simpleType>
                      </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="WindowSize"/>
                    <xs:attribute name="type" type="xs:string" use="required" fixed="System.Drawing.Size"/>
                  </xs:complexType>
                </xs:alternative>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```